# How to make function chainable without executing? like `obj.fn.fn` instead of `obj.fn().fn()`

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I have two functions in an object

```
var obj = {};
obj.fn1 = function(){ console.log('obj.fn1'); return this; };
obj.fn2 = function(){ console.log('obj.fn2'); return this; };
```

I want to be able to do

```
obj.fn1.fn2()
obj.fn2.fn1()
```

How to do this?

EDIT: `fn1` and `fn2` could be functions or property accessors, I don't care as long as they *do stuff*.

I've seen it in many libraries, like [chalk](https://github.com/sindresorhus/chalk) `color.red.bold('string')`.

Comment: You cannot do that. Since functions in javascript are first-class values, it's imperative that you can differentiate between a function, and the return value of one. When you see `color.red.bold`, the chaining is through property lookups of objects, not functions.

Comment: @doldt `color.red` behaves like a property in `color.red.bold(..)` but like a function in `color.red(..)`. So properties can behave like functions? I don't get it

Comment: I can get half way there — http://jsfiddle.net/knn8pu5m/ — but I can't figure out how to allow the last property accessed to be callable as a function as well as being something you can chain from. It would help if you gave a specific example rather then just saying "many libraries".

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just getting rid of the parentheses? That is, do you want `obj.fn1.fn2` to do the exact same thing as `obj.fn1().fn2()`? I'm asking because the question title is quite different from the question text and the answers already here. Are you trying to avoid *execution*, or the *invocation syntax*?

Comment: ES6 getters might be able to achieve this (although it would be a bit mischevious because the getter would only ever be able to return the chainable object). I would recommend against it, but it's there.. basically you want to use a method without using a method.

Comment: @DanPantry getters/setters are in ES5

Comment: @laggingreflex you can add properties to function objects. Consider this: `var color=function(){...}; color.red='red'`. Here you can both call `color()`, or reference `color.red` as a property.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if `fn1`, `fn2` and `obj` have references to both functions. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (ES6) helps here:

```
var base = {
  fn1: function fn1() { console.log('fn1'); return this; },
  fn2: function fn2() { console.log('fn2'); return this; }
}

Object.assign(base.fn1, base);
Object.assign(base.fn2, base);
var obj = Object.assign({}, base);

obj.fn1();
obj.fn1.fn2();
obj.fn2();
obj.fn1.fn2.fn1.fn1();
```

[babel.js repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20base%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fn1%3A%20function%20fn1()%20%7B%20console.log('fn1')%3B%20return%20this%3B%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fn2%3A%20function%20fn2()%20%7B%20console.log('fn2')%3B%20return%20this%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Object.assign(base.fn1%2C%20base)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Object.assign(base.fn2%2C%20base)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20var%20obj%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20base)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20obj.fn1()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20obj.fn1.fn2()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20obj.fn2()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20obj.fn1.fn2.fn1.fn1()%3B%0A)

I expect this is how your library example works.

If [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is not available you could use a [polyfill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign) or common alternative like [`_.assign`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) from lodash.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just some nested objects. Take a look at this code:

```js
function Color(c) { this.color = c; }
Color.prototype.bold = function(text) { return '<strong style="color: ' + this.color + '">' + text + '</strong>'; }

var colors = {
  red: new Color('red'),
  blue: new Color('blue')
}

document.write(
  colors.red.bold('text'));

document.write(
  colors.blue.bold('text'));
```